# Distorted audio, lagging mouse, slow speed, no internet

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, connection, desktop-computer

So when I turn on my computer now the windows booting sound is all distorted almost like it's stretched or crackling, when I log in the mouse lags, and everything seems to load a bit longer. It can see all wifi connections but it says only limited connectivity when i try one, which really just means no connectivity. This is all happening after ignoring an error that kept popping up over the last month, where after the message appeared I would be practically unable to do anything until I restarted the computer. The message was “Instruction at referenced memory could not be read”. That message doesn't really show up anymore but that might be just cause I'm not on long enough to trigger it (no reason to stay on a pc you can't use). I'm on windows 7, I have an AMD FX-8350 Processor, and 16GB ram (was 8GB, I literally just installed the other 8 after this issue started hoping it might help). I have also ran it in safe mode where none of these issues seem to occur.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: This error can be caused by bad memory, a bad CPU, older drivers, hardware conflicts, and so on. Please check the lnk below for detailed info on this issue
 
 http://helpdeskgeek.com/help-desk/instruction-at-referenced-memory-could-not-be-read/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but this recently happened to me as well.

Found out it was due to 1027 Windows 6 to 4 tunnel adapters.

Easiest way to check if this is the issue is to open a command prompt and run **ipconfig**. If this is the fault, you'll have a massive list of the 6 to 4 tunnel adapters. These are hidden within system devices, but you can view them by performing:

1. Open Control Panel | System | Device Manager
2. Expand **Network adapters**
3. Go to **View** | **Show Hidden Devices**

You'll see them all listed here. You can remove them 1 by 1, but for a thousand adapters, this gets tedious.

I used the Windows 7 [WDK](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjnjo7kvdPMAhVLw4MKHW-vAy0QFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-ca%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D11800&usg=AFQjCNFAPyXpIEyLokaEgKN9V9JBGtKaZA&sig2=W6lqWKyAwZ7h9L3PasSikQ)

In the Tools folder after installing it, there's a tool called devcon.

Open a command prompt with Administrator privileges, and run the following:

> devcon remove *6to4mp

This removes all the 6to4 tunnel adapters (which are only useful if you have an ipv6 network only, and noone really does).

System runs fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

If your first ram stick got fried and is causing errors, adding a functional one in addition wouldn't resolve the crashing problem.

You should run memtest off some bootable media -- download to usb or cdrom, run via BIOS. It may be as simple as removing the old ram stick and running on your new 8gig stick (and sending the fried stick back to the manufacturer if you're under warranty).

Note: aware this should properly go as a comment, as it is not a solution, but a first step... I simply don't have the rep yet... please don't down-vote me accordingly. I will be sure to remove it and post as comment when I have 50.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have tried removing the old ram but it didn't help, I also ran a memtest but it couldn't find any problem. The only things left I can think of is that it's either being caused by a program, a driver, or my processor is getting buggy.

Comment: Humph. Well, if memtest shows no write errors I would refer you to vembutech's linked post. Run msconfig to check for weird startup items first though (easy first step); then as suggested check your drivers; check the drive for hard disk issues; run system restore to a point before the problem manifested; and then if all else fails back up critical files if you can and just do a clean reinstall of windows. Shouldn't let a 16gig ram system rot.